# Deleting message notifciations in DiscordJS

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is there a way to delete notifications from Discord when deleting a message? I have an "anonymous" command that lets a user type a message and deletes that message instantly, after which the bot sends the message. The problem is that a notification is still sent and everyone on mobile or active on pc will be able to see the author. Can I delete the notification or prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm pretty sure that notifications can not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the notification, but you can configure the server so that by default users will not receive a notification if they are not explicitly mentioned in that message.

Your server> Server settings> Overview> Default notification settings> Only @mentions